# Should I need to use ConcurrentHashMap when writes needs to work based reads

Tags: java, performance

I'm currently working with threads. I used a hashmap with `synchronized`.

I came to know that it is performance overhead, so I am looking for `ConcurrentHashMap`. My logic needs to check if the value exists in the collection object by defining if and else block.

Example:

```
synchronized(hashMap){   
    String a = Hashmap.get(id);   
    if(a != null){   
        update   
    } else {
        adding different key and values   
    }   
}
```

Based on read value I am writing to hashmap. In this case, can I replace hashmap to `ConcurrentHashMap` because I know read i.e retrival will not lock. So will it becomes concurrency problem.

Comment: Use `Map.merge` and `Map.compute` and `Map.computeIfAbsent` etc. with `ConcurrentHashMap` in order to obtain the performance benefit. You need to carry out _atomic_ operations, let the `Map` to the work.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: so in my code if i replace just hashmap to concurrentHashMap by removing synchronized keyword then concurrency problem may happens right?

Comment: Yes, because the thread safety guarantees would apply only to the individual methods. You need to rewrite your code so that it doesn't rely on the lock around multiple individual calls.

Comment: In my server i am using java version 7.so until i update jdk i cannot use ConcurrentHashMap in my usecase code it seems.

Comment: Worth noting that Java 7 [reached EOL in April 2015](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/05/Oracle-Ends-Java-7Public-Updates).

Comment: yes i checked.I should upgrade it.I don't know what kind of compatibility problem comes if i switch to higher version other then deprecated functionalities.